# How common are tripled pawns in chess games?

Tags: statistics, pawn-structure, doubled-pawn

Recently I played a nice OTB game where I sacked a pawn to triple my enemy's pawns, and won convincingly. Having played thousands of games online and dozens OTB, I somehow fail to remember any other games where either side had tripled pawns. I was wondering how common tripled pawns are, possibly based on rating, and if there are any examples of top-level games with tripled, or even quadrupled, pawns. And for context, some info about the frequency of doubled pawns (which I expect is decently high) would be appreciated.

Additionally, are there any relatively main-line or at least somewhat reasonable openings that lead to tripled pawns (presumably with decent compensation)?

Edit: in case this was unclear, I specifically want to know about what percentage of games contained doubled/tripled/quadrupled pawns.

Comment: How long do the doubled or tripled pawns have to persist for to count?  In a game with the exchange QGD (1. d4 d5 2. c4 e6 3. cd ed) were there doubled pawns already?

Comment: Good question. I think any doubled pawns that aren't immediately recaptured after being created can qualify, though there might be some weird cases with an in-between capture, but that should be pretty rare.